# when i enter new value in my primary combox i want my other combox to check SQL DB AND auto complete if it all ready there , or stay blank if not?

Tags: c#

I WANT TO MAKE A TRIGGER THAT CLEAR MY COMBO BOXS , WHEN I TRY TO ENTER NEW DATA INTO MY PRIMARY COMBO BOX ?

THIS IS MY CODE , WHICH CONNECT TO db AND BRINGS THE DATA FROM IT , I WANT TO KNOW HOW I CAN MAKE A TRIGGER THAT CLEAR THE REST OF THE COMBO BOXS ACCORDING TO MY PRIMARY WHEN I ENTER NEW DATA

```
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("server=CH-PC; integrated security = true ; database = finalproject");
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from books ", cn);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "books");
            comboBox3.DataSource = ds.Tables["books"];
            comboBox3.DisplayMember = "book_ispn";

        if (comboBox3.DisplayMember != "") {          

            SqlDataAdapter daa = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from books where book_ispn= " + comboBox3.Text, cn);
            DataSet dss = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(dss, "books");
            comboBox4.DataSource = ds.Tables["books"];
            comboBox4.DisplayMember = "book_name";

            SqlDataAdapter daaa = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from books where book_ispn= " + comboBox3.Text, cn);
            DataSet dsss = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(dsss, "books");
            comboBox5.DataSource = ds.Tables["books"];
            comboBox5.DisplayMember = "book_author";

            SqlDataAdapter daaaa = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from books where book_ispn= " + comboBox3.Text, cn);
            DataSet dssss = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(dssss, "books");
            comboBox6.DataSource = ds.Tables["books"];
            comboBox6.DisplayMember = "book_publisher";

            SqlDataAdapter jaa = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from books where book_ispn= " + comboBox3.Text, cn);
            DataSet kss = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(kss, "books");
            comboBox7.DataSource = ds.Tables["books"];
            comboBox7.DisplayMember = "book_edition";

            SqlDataAdapter jaas = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from books where book_ispn= " + comboBox3.Text, cn);
            DataSet ksas = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ksas, "books");
            comboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables["books"];
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "school_name";

            SqlDataAdapter jasas = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from books where book_ispn= " + comboBox3.Text, cn);
            DataSet ksaas = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ksaas, "books");
            comboBox2.DataSource = ds.Tables["books"];
            comboBox2.DisplayMember = "major_code";

        }
```

Comment: Looks like your Caps Lock key got stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You are either going to have to write some JavaScript to handle this (JQuery makes this quite trivial) or look into getting hold of a 3rd party control that handles this.  The AjaxControlToolkit has a "cascading dropdown" control extender that might work.

```
$("#<%= comboBox3.ID %>").on("change", function(){
    $("#<%= comboBox4.ID %>").val('');
    $("#<%= comboBox5.ID %>").val('');
    $("#<%= comboBox6.ID %>").val('');
    ....
});
```